# How to allow user to pick a color to display on a particular row on listview

Tags: android

I have a fragment and an activity. The Fragment contains a listview, the activity contains four buttons which are colors, now the question is when the user click on any color they want in Activity I want that color to be the background color of a particular row on the listview  in fragment. Help please.   ![Activity Form][1] 
For clear explanation the link below shows my activity view which  contains a form the data is stored to Sqlite DB and user can choose which ever color they want, after the data is stored to DB. 
Now the fragment comes in. The Data will populate to a listview from DB  on the fragment and also containing the color chosen by the user as the background of that row.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlUxo.png

Answer (score 0):

From Activity you send color with intent as:

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("Color",color);
//set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj=new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  int backgroundcolor=getArguments().getInt("name");
  listview.setbackgroundColor(backgroundcolor);

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: The App crash. Is crashing because of this line int backgroundcolor=getArguments().getInt("name");

Comment: @user3837988 what does logcat says?

Comment: 07-17 03:16:03.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 03:16:03.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26349): Process: com.example.viewpagertimetable, PID: 26349
07-17 03:16:03.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26349): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 03:16:03.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):  at com.example.viewpagertimetable.Monday.onCreateView(Monday.java:65)
07-17 03:16:03.281: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)

Comment: could u please edit the question and post your code here. it would be helpful

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question for the clear explanation hope this helps.